# Streaming output of a remotely executed program via ssh

Tags: python, ssh

Is it possible to stream the output of a program that is being executed via ssh?

Example program (test.py on remote):

```
import time
while True:
    print time.time()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Command (local):

```
ssh name@remote 'python test.py'
```

Since the program never terminates, the output is not streamed; is this possible in some way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently, adding the -t option to the ssh command works. It flushes the stdout:

```
ssh -t name@remote 'python test.py'
```